# How to select multiple file in android

Tags: java, android, android-image

I use following code to select file but i can select one file only. How can i select more then one file.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
 .....



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User has picked an image. 
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    //File URI.. 

}
```

thank u

Comment: Android Gallery allows you to select only one file at a time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom gallery of your own.More info can be had from here.
[Android custom image gallery](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)